# Running a DPDK application binary with all dependent library (compiled in different machine) on another machine

Tags: dpdk

- A DPDK application with several runtime dependent libraries are compiled on one machine
- Binaries and libraries are copied from that machine to another machine with similar specs and environment
- Running the DPDK application with the parameters as given below, but the application crashes during `rte_eal_init()`

```
 App-binary -l 1 -a 0000:02:00.0 -a 0000:03:00.0 -d /opt/upf/lib/ --proc-type=primary --file-prefix=.app_0000:02:00.0
```

- This is the back trace from gnu debugger crash core file

```
    #0  0x00007faaa0ead337 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #1  0x00007faaa0eaea28 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #2  0x00007faaa125104f in __rte_panic () from /opt/upf/lib/librte_eal.so.21
    #3  0x00007faa9e228e1c in tailqinitfn_rte_ring_tailq () from /opt/upf/lib/librte_ring.so.21.0
    #4  0x00007faaa278a973 in _dl_init_internal () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    #5  0x00007faaa278f54e in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    #6  0x00007faaa278a784 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    #7  0x00007faaa278eb3b in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    #8  0x00007faaa0c73eeb in dlopen_doit () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
    #9  0x00007faaa278a784 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    #10 0x00007faaa0c744ed in _dlerror_run () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
    #11 0x00007faaa0c73f81 in dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
    #12 0x00007faaa125bc55 in eal_plugins_init () from /opt/upf/lib/librte_eal.so.21
    #13 0x00007faaa126f2ba in rte_eal_init () from /opt/upf/lib/librte_eal.so.21
    #14 0x000000000041414a in Dpdk_LibTask (arg=<optimized out>) at /root/5g_upf/core/service/common/dpdk/dpdk.c:1244
    #15 0x00007faaa2566e65 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    #16 0x00007faaa0f7588d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Updates:

- Host Machine details:

  - i3 8100 3.6GHz 4 Cores
  - 8 GB RAM
  - CentOS 7
  - gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC)
  - GNU ld version 2.27-44.base.el7
  - DPDK 20.11.0
  - 3 NICs bounded to DPDK

    ```
    0000:01:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e
    0000:07:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e
    0000:08:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e
    ```
- Target Machine details:

  - i3 8100 3.6GHz 4 Cores
  - 8 GB RAM
  - CentOS 7
  - gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC)
  - GNU ld version 2.27-44.base.el7
  - DPDK 20.11.0
  - 3 NICs bounded to DPDK

    ```
    0000:02:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e
    0000:03:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e
    0000:04:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e
    ```

Comment: please update the information of host machine, target machine and logs with eal option `--log-level=8`. The right way of doing this is `installing the the libraries on target machine and not copying it over`. Did you also run `ldconfig` after copying?

Comment: @VipinVarghese I updated my post with Host and Target machine details, and I tried running it with `--log-level=8` but it didn't help as program is completely crashing when `rte_eal_init` is called, I also tried running `ldconfig`, no change in outcome

Comment: 'log-level=8` is not to fix things but to collect the DPDK logs

Comment: Host & target machine details are `OS name, gcc version. binutils version numbers`

Comment: would be comfortable for a live debug?

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have added `gcc version and binutils version` . I am logging off for the week, I will come back to that question of live debug and log-level once I return.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Can we proceed with the live debug?

Comment: @VipinVarghese How about 5pm IST? Here is the link https://meet.google.com/xvu-xttt-bii

Comment: @VipinVarghese How about you suggest a time tomorrow? same link

Comment: @VipinVarghese How about today 12PM IST or you can suggest a time according to your availability(the same link)

Comment: @VipinVarghese Sorry can you join back got disconnected

Comment: @VipinVarghese you can join back anytime I am there till 5PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on the live debug with Sumesh].

Application background:

1. The application has dependency on DPDK libraries, 3rd party libraries and GNU libraries.
2. Actual open source project, builds DPDK 20.11.
3. Docker instance is started with `docker run` where root permission is shared and  and copies these over to a local folder (same machine).
4. With LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to desired folder DPDK libraries dependency are corrected.

What caused the issues:

1. Machine-A is used to build the DPDK 20.11 libraries.
2. Instead of running docker instance on Machine-A, Machine-B is choose as target machine.
3. DPDK libraries are copied from Machine-A to Machine-B.
4. Docker-run is used to start the application in Machine-B

How to fix the issue:

1. DPDK libraries when built has numerous other libraries and version dependency
2. Build and install DPDK on target (MACHINE-B) and do not copy.
3. in `docker-run` share the permission to access the `/usr/lib/lib64` which houses DPDK, 3rd party and GNU Libraries.
4. update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have access to right folder to resolve the dependency.

Note:

1. Tested and validated on both Host and Docker with hello-world for sanity
2. Sumesh is updating the scripts to reflect the folder permission for the custom application.